# How to use Datatables server-side processing with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, datatables, server-side

I'm trying to use datatables in server-side processing mode whereby data is loaded in *batches*, asynchronously. This is *very* useful for massive datasets. The documentation is clear enough (https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html), however, I'm struggling to work out how to implement it within Google Apps Script and its HTMLService.

What I'm currently using (which is working) is datatables **loading all the data in at once**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadLogList).getLogList();
});

function loadLogList(data) {
  if (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      htmlString += "<tr><td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>";
      htmlString += "<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>";
      htmlString += "<td>" + data[i][2] + "</td>";
      htmlString += "<td>" + data[i][3] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    $("#LogListBody").html(htmlString);
  }

  var table = $("#LogList").DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
      { "orderData":[ 0 ],   "targets": [ 1 ] },
      {
      "targets": [ 0 ],
      "visible": false,
      "searchable": false
      } ],
    "paging": true,
    "select": true
  });
}
```

The documentation suggests that datatables needs initialising like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

So somehow I need to provide "ajax" with "google.script.run". Any ideas? I then need to write a function on the server-side (Code.gs) to return json-formatted data. If anyone has sample code for this also I'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs ajax can be configured in a few different way.  One is by providing a custom function.
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Edit based on more info from op. This is the very basic setup:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true, 
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).getLogList(settings);
  }
} );
```

Comment: The plugin already parses what's loaded into the DOM. I want to move to an asynchronous scheme where data is pulled when it is needed.

Comment: Get it. You want to scrap the code you posted then. Take a look at the docs I posted about using a custom function for the ajax call.

Comment: @SpencerEaston I'm having the exact same problem as the OP. I tried your code but it returns `Failed due to illegal value in property: ajax`. Due you have an idea why it does that? Also is using `callback` in withSuccessHandler method correct?