# How to use DataTables Server side processing and ajax with Google Apps script

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a scenario similar to the one posted here:
[Using DataTables Server side processing with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505161/how-to-use-datatables-server-side-processing-with-google-apps-script)

I'm currently using DataTables together with GAS. I have a PHP API in a remote server that has access to a MySQL database.
Within GAS, I use UrLFetch to query the database through the API which in turn returns the data in JSON format. My current implementation fetches all the data from the databaseand uses DataTables create the table with the fetched data.
However my database is continuously getting bigger and I want to use the server side processing feature with ajax to take care of the heavy load in the server side.
I'm struggling to work out how to implement it within GAS and its HTMLService. I don't know if my thinking process is right (perhaps I am over complicating things) but what I want to do is:
jQuery DataTables->GAS HTMLService->PHP API->MySQL--(data)-->PHP API->GAS HTMLService-> jQuery DataTables

From the stackoverflow link above calling `google.script.run` in the ajax function should do trick but it does not work for me. I get the error, `Uncaught TypeError: Failed due to illegal value in property: ajax`.
I am particularly unclear about how using `callback` and `settings` variable in `google.script.run` method helps in this case.
Here's the code:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true, 
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).getLogList(settings);
  }
} );
```

This is the manual for DataTables server side processing.
[DataTables Server Side Manual](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)
As it's mentioned in the manual, DataTables sends various data to the server,
in order to let the server know what is required. From my desired implementation, these data should be sent to GAS (through GET method I suppose),
then GAS gets the data through the `e` parameter in `doGet(e)` and then queries the PHP API.
Which makes the above code confusing since the data sent to the server is contained in `draw` and not `settings`. Replacing `settings` with `data` returns  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aaData' of undefined` though.

I don't understand how I can go about this implementation.
I'd be very grateful, if anyone can put me in the right direction. A sample code would be of great help!

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a jdbc connection to your database.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for your suggestion. Using a jdbc connection means I'll have to whitelist some Google IP addresses, which isn't an option in my case. It doesn't change the fact that I'll still have pass through GAS in order to access database.